# App Size increased after androidx (including react-native) migration

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I have done androidX migration in android project and to do so I have to migrate react from 0.59.8 to 0.60.3

Migration was successfull, but my app size has increased due to increase in dex file size

No new feature code change/added in-between migration.

Android change
Gradle file support dependencies change and imports changed

React change
0.59.8 to 0.63 and enabled HermesVm

Existing Dex size from aab inspect bundle/apk

[image: Existing Dex size from aab inspect bundle/apk]

New Dex size from aab inspect bundle/apk

[image: New Dex size from aab inspect bundle/apk]

Comment: I had this happen to me too recently. I think it is because I added 64-bit support. I was updating from RN 0.44.3 to RN 0.59.9. This is possibly what you're seeing too?

Comment: In 0.59.8 also there was 64 bit support, so this is not the reason, And in 64 bit support only lib(so) files size increases

Comment: Ah ok - just a thought. Hope you find the culprit!

Comment: I'm going to assume because AndroidX is different that it simply includes stuff here that takes up considerably more space, you had to include more, or you included something more in AndroidX than you realize. I don't think it was 1:1 in other words and this is the current result. I feel its either this or something else did change.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, and exactly what I have included more is I don't know, and it's not descriptive enough from the dex files. But I assure that no new line of code is added except the change in dependencies